# convert xml with mulitple tags under text element in to simple text

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xml like

```
<text>La <concept descr="lnf:dsc#thm1421299" length="29" />composition du
<concept descr="lnf:dsc#thm2265557" length="22" />domaine public fluvial implique
au-delà d'une définition de critères légaux (V. nÂ°Â <link refpt="N1">1</link> et
<link refpt="N2">2</link>) un travail de caractérisation et de classification des
différentes catégories naturelle, artificielle ou mobilière de
<concept descr="lnf:dsc#thm2265557" length="22" />domaine public fluvial (V. nÂ°Â
<link refpt="N3">3</link> Ã  24).</text>
```

I want convert this xml to simple text using xslt by removing the concept tag and outputting only descr values as text.

Output e.g.

> La lnf:dsc#thm1421299 composition du lnf:dsc#thm2265557 domaine public
>   fluvial implique au-delÃ  d'une dÃ©finition de critÃ¨res lÃ©gaux .....

Can you please tell me how can I write an xslt rule for this?

I have written this xslt code for this

```
<xsl:template match="concept" mode="concatthem">
    <xsl:value-of select="@descr"/>
  </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*|text()" mode="concatthem"/>
```

does it looks good ?

Comment: It helps to know what you have already tried.

Comment: Please be more careful with the character encoding.

Answer (score 0):

If that's really your entire XML document, you just need to do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method='text'/>

<xsl:template match="/text">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="concept">
    <xsl:value-of select="@descr"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Michael but seems to be it is not working. I am getting

Comment: empty tag in my output pivot layer.

Comment: This is output <texts>
<FASCICULE_LEVEL/>
<FASCICULE_LEVEL2/>
<FASCICULE_LEVEL2/>
<ENCYCLO_TITLE/>
</texts> here is the input  <text>L'article L.Â 2111-1 du Code gÃ©nÃ©ral de la propriÃ©tÃ© des personnes publiques constitue la dÃ©finition positive et moderne de la <concept descr="lnf:dsc#thm1421282" length="24" />............

Comment: <xsl:template name="xpath_to_normalize">
    <xsl:param name="xpath"/>
    <xsl:param name="tag"/>
    <xsl:if test="$xpath">
      <xsl:variable name="tmp">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$xpath"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:element name="{$tag}">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($tmp)"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(normalize-space(.), ' ')"/>
  </xsl:template>

Comment: @atilthakor Please read carefully what I wrote at the beginning of my answer: **"If that's really your entire XML document"**. If it's not, please edit your question and post your REAL input. If it is, and you are getting `<FASCICULE_LEVEL/>` in your output without having it in the input, then it's a miracle and I am not going to interfere with the divine.

Comment: Hi Micheal, can i know how i can add descr value from concept tag at the end of the all texts.e.g.20Â avr. 1956, Dpt Hautes-AlpesÂ : AJDA 1956, p.Â 18, concl. Long) ou encore de la dÃ©cision de financement (CE, 26Â janv. 1927, RaynaudÂ : Rec. CE 1927, p.Â 105) lnf:dsc#thm1421313 lnf:dsc#thm1421313 lnf:dsc#thm1421281 lnf:dsc#thm2265557 lnf:dsc#thm2265557 lnf:dsc#thm2265557 lnf:dsc#thm1402749 lnf:dsc#thm1402749

Comment: @atilthakor The input in your question is the same as it was before. Now, if you have another question, then either edit your question here or start a new one.

Comment: ok i am posting new question within couple of Minutes. Thanks Micheal.

Comment: Michael, I have posted another question "Transforming XML tags within text and put the xml tag value at end of the text" Let me know if you need more details.